# How can i stop the inputs border color from changing when the user clicks it

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to make a form for my website and there is two problems that i am facing
the first problem is when i put an input for example :

```
<textarea cols:40 rows:50></textarea>
```

If you clicked on that in chrome the border-color will change into orange and in safari it will change into blue so how can i stop the color changing in border?

Comment: Not cols:40 but also cols="40" etc ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `outline`:

```
textarea {
    outline: none;
}
```

Bear in mind, though, that the `outline` is used to indicate the focused form-field, which may be useful as an accessibility aid to some disabled/limited-vision users; it's always worth making an effort to replace the default visual cue with another, that fits your theme, whether by changing the `color` of the `outline` or by using `background-color` on the element itself.

Also your HTML is malformed, it should be:

```
<textarea rows="50" cols="40"></textarea>
```

References:

- [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/outline).

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove outline on focus:

```
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```